# Unit test custom NLog target

Tags: c#, azure, nlog

I have an NLog target I've written that is intended to take the NLog LogEventInfo and write it to Azure's API services. I'm having trouble writing a unit test for the logger because I can't figure out how to intercept the message being logged to APIServices.Log.Trace.

Here's the target definition:

```
namespace Ariel.Mobile.Logging
{
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Tracing;

using Ariel.Library;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;

using Ninject;

using NLog;
using NLog.Targets;

/// <summary>
/// Class to be used with NLog to write error and debug data to Azure for storage.
/// </summary>
[Target("Azure")]
public class AzureTarget : Target
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the mappings between NLog and Azure levels.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly IDictionary<LogLevel, TraceLevel> LevelMap =
        new Dictionary<LogLevel, TraceLevel>
            {
                { LogLevel.Trace, TraceLevel.Debug }, 
                { LogLevel.Debug, TraceLevel.Debug }, 
                { LogLevel.Info, TraceLevel.Info }, 
                { LogLevel.Warn, TraceLevel.Warn }, 
                { LogLevel.Error, TraceLevel.Error }, 
                { LogLevel.Fatal, TraceLevel.Fatal }
            };

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Azure service to which messages will be sent.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ApiServices services;
    #endregion

    public AzureTarget()
    {
        services = new ApiServices(ServiceConfig.Config);
    }

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Method accepting NLog logging events to be transmitted to Azure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logEvent">The NLog event which needs to be persisted.
    /// </param>
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        this.services.Log.Trace(LevelMap[logEvent.Level], logEvent.Message, logEvent.Exception);
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

How can I intercept the message being logged to APIServices.Log.Trace in my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

You will be able to use a Shim to intercept the call.